# How can I check if a text channel is already in a category? Discord Rewrite API for Bot

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

I'm trying to make a ticket function on Discord on my bot, and I was wondering how I can check in a certain category whether a text channel already exists, and if it does, then the ticket won't be created.

```
@bot.command()
async def new(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    channel = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=404351895121952768)
    if ctx.message.channel != bot.get_channel(402168280149655552):
        tag = await bot.get_channel(402168280149655552).send("{}".format(ctx.message.author.mention))
        wrongchannel_embed = discord.Embed(title="Error:",
                                           description="Use my commands in the {} channel.".format(tag.channel.mention),
                                           color=0xe73c24)
        await ctx.send(embed=wrongchannel_embed)
    elif discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name='{}-ticket'.format(ctx.message.author.name)):
        failed_embed = discord.Embed(title="Failed to create a ticket",
                                     description="You already have a ticket open, please don't try to open a ticket while you already have one.",
                                     color=0xe73c24)
        await ctx.send(embed=failed_embed)
    else:
        print(channel)
        print(guild.categories)
        overwrites = {
            guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
            ctx.message.author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
        }
        ticket_create = await guild.create_text_channel(name='{}-ticket'.format(ctx.message.author.name),
                                                        overwrites=overwrites, category=channel)
        ticket_embed = discord.Embed(title="Ticket",
                                     description="{}\nPlease be patient. A member of our support team will be with you shortly.".format(
                                         ctx.message.author.mention),
                                     color=0x15a513)
        ticket_embed.set_footer(text="Ticket requested by {}".format(ctx.message.author),
                                icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        await ticket_create.send(embed=ticket_embed)
        success_embed = discord.Embed(title="Ticket Creation",
                                      description="{}, your ticket was successfully created: {1}.".format(
                                          ctx.message.author.mention, ticket_create.mention),
                                      color=0x15a513)
        await ctx.send(embed=success_embed)
```

That's my code for creating the ticket. The line I'm focusing on is `elif discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name='{}-ticket'.format(ctx.message.author.name)):`
I know I'm doing something wrong there. I also tried:
`elif "{}-ticket".format(ctx.message.author.name) in discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name="Tickets"):`
but it didn't work.

Any idea on what I can do?

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are having? Are you getting an error when you try to run the code, are you just not seeing any results...

Comment: @qspitzer
Managed to find the solution. Basically what was happening was even though I was checking for the name of the ticket in the category and telling it to not create a new ticket with a certain name if it found one with that name, it was still creating a text channel with the name I didn't want it to. I managed to fix it by changing `elif discord.utils.get(channel.channels, name="{}-ticket".format(ctx.message.author.name))` to `elif discord.utils.get(channel.channels, name="{}-ticket".format(ctx.message.author.name.lower()))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could've been a case-sensitive issue:

```py
elif discord.utils.get(channel.channels, name=f"{ctx.author.name.lower()}-ticket"):
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out the solution. Basically what was happening was I was checking it correctly, but it was searching for the command sender's name *with* capital letters, but the name of the tickets are in lower case. So what I did was change `elif discord.utils.get(channel.channels, name="{}-ticket".format(ctx.message.author.name))` to `elif discord.utils.get(channel.channels, name="{}-ticket".format(ctx.message.author.name.lower()))`

I hope this can help some of you.